# callback on foursquare like and follow buttons

Tags: callback, foursquare

Is it possible to have a callback URL on foursquare  Web buttons when they have been successfully clicked?

Is it as simple as just including a redirect_url attribute in the html?

Answer (score 0):

You can try capturing the click event client-side and using that information as you wish.